# GameState Management efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, xna

So I've read numerous tutorials on handling game states in XNA, and to each tutorial I've been read, it was different from the others. Now I want to ask which way is more efficient? I've created my own ScreenManager and what not, but it wasn't satisfying to me because it was inefficient since I didn't unload any unused content.

My question is: What is an efficient way to manage your screens and its content? Is using an enum fine? Or...?

Here's my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Menu
{
    public class ScreenManager
    {
        // Variables
        List<GameScreen> gameScreens = new List<GameScreen>();

        // Constructors
        public ScreenManager()
        {
            gameScreens.Add(new Splashscreen());
            gameScreens.Add(new Mainscreen());
            gameScreens.Add(new Playscreen());
            gameScreens.Add(new Pausescreen());
        }

        // Public Properties
        public List<GameScreen> Screens
        {
            get { return gameScreens; }
            set { gameScreens = value; }
        }

        // Public Methods
        public void Add(GameScreen screen)
        {
            gameScreens.Add(screen);
        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            foreach (GameScreen screen in gameScreens)
            {
                screen.LoadContent(Content);
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            foreach (GameScreen screen in gameScreens)
            {
                screen.Update(gameTime);
            }
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            switch (ScreenState.Instance.CurrentState)
            {
                case State.Splashscreen:
                    gameScreens[0].Draw(spriteBatch);
                    break;
                case State.Menu:
                    gameScreens[1].Draw(spriteBatch);
                    break;
                case State.Play:
                    gameScreens[2].Draw(spriteBatch);
                    break;
                case State.Pause:
                    gameScreens[3].Draw(spriteBatch);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure of this (I need to foster my XNA knowledge), but I would probably derive that class from `DrawableGameComponent` so that the `Update` and `Draw` methods would be overrides (not just methods that happen to be named "Update" and "Draw"), but deriving from that class might have other consequences that I'm not aware of; again, my XNA is fairly basic - it just seems natural to me for a class that has `Update` and a `Draw` methods, to derive from `DrawableGameComponent`: these method names are not an accident.

#### Update

Your `Update()` method is looping through each `GameScreen` and calling `Update()` on them all:

> ```
> foreach (GameScreen screen in gameScreens)
> {
>     screen.Update(gameTime);
> }
> ```

I think doing this incurs non-necessary processing: why would you bother updating the *splash screen* and *pause screen* at every single iteration? You're wasting cycles here.

#### Draw

Your `Draw()` method is more selective:

> ```
> public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
> {
>     switch (ScreenState.Instance.CurrentState)
>     {
>         case State.Splashscreen:
>             gameScreens[0].Draw(spriteBatch);
>             break;
>         case State.Menu:
>             gameScreens[1].Draw(spriteBatch);
>             break;
>         case State.Play:
>             gameScreens[2].Draw(spriteBatch);
>             break;
>         case State.Pause:
>             gameScreens[3].Draw(spriteBatch);
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```

I like that you're using an enum here, but I don't like that you've hard-coded the `gameScreens` indices. Let's see.. you're storing the screens in a `List`, here:

> ```
> List<GameScreen> gameScreens = new List<GameScreen>();
>
> public ScreenManager()
> {
>     gameScreens.Add(new Splashscreen());
>     gameScreens.Add(new Mainscreen());
>     gameScreens.Add(new Playscreen());
>     gameScreens.Add(new Pausescreen());
> }
> ```

Allow me to open a nitpicking parenthesis here:

> **Nitpick**
>
> Instead of `List<GameScreen> gameScreens = new List<GameScreen>();` and then adding the screens in the list at construction, I would have used an interface here, and initialized everything in a single statement:
>
> ```
> private readonly IList<GameScreen> _gameScreens;
>
> public ScreenManager()
> {
>     _gameScreens = new List<GameScreen> 
>                            {
>                                new SplashScreen(),
>                                new MainScreen(),
>                                new PlayScreen(),
>                                new PauseScreen()
>                            };
> }
> ```
>
> This allows the `_gameScreens` private field to be `readonly`, which prevents the list's reference to be tampered with.

The mechanics *work*, but could work *better* if you leveraged `IDictionary` and turned `List<GameScreen> gameScreens` into a `IDictionary<State, Action<SpriteBatch>>`:

```
private readonly IDictionary<State, Action<SpriteBatch>> _gameScreenRenderer;
private readonly GameScreen _splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
private readonly GameScreen _mainScreen = new MainScreen();
private readonly GameScreen _playScreen = new PlayScreen();
private readonly GameScreen _pauseScreen = new PauseScreen();

public ScreenManager()
{
    _gameScreenRenderer = new Dictionary<State, Action<SpriteBatch>>
                            {
                                { State.SplashScreen, sb => _splashScreen.Draw(sb) },
                                { State.MainScreen, sb => _mainScreen.Draw(sb) },
                                { State.PlayScreen, sb => _playScreen.Draw(sb) },
                                { State.PauseScreen, sb => _pauseScreen.Draw(sb) }
                            };
}
```

An `Action<SpriteBatch>` is a delegate that points to any method that returns `void` and takes a `SpriteBatch` parameter; here the method is anonymous.

Each `GameScreen` becomes a field of the `ScreenManager` class, there's no need to have them in a list of any kind. Doing this turns your `Draw` implementation into something like this:

```
private void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    _gameScreenRenderer[ScreenState.Instance.CurrentState](spriteBatch);
}
```

Implement a similar mechanism for your `Update` method and you'll only be updating and rendering the screen for your `CurrentState`.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the flaws of this code. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Thank **you** for asking here on CodeReview! Come back anytime, there's always someone around here to review C# code :)